# Projectig certain sub documents in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a timeseries data which looks like follows

```
"data": {
    "a": {
        "T": [
            1652167964645,
            1652168781684,
            1652168781720,
            1652169266156,
            1652169267146,
            1652169272796,
            1652169299338
        ],
        "V": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            10,
            6,
            1252,
            1555
        ]
    },
    "b": {
        "T": [
            1652167961657,
            1652168781720,
            1652168781818,
            1652168787377,
            1652168835734,
            1652169266108,
            1652169266125,
            1652169272798,
            1652169299328
        ],
        "V": [
            1,
            3,
            4,
            6,
            12,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            1
        ]
    },
    "c": {
        "T": [
            1652167960194,
            1652168787377,
            1652169266108,
            1652169272798,
            1652169299328
        ],
        "V": [
            1,
            3,
            17,
            18,
            1
        ]
    }}
```

inside the sub documents there are time and values
I can process the data in total. but if I want tp process only two sub document how can i do that ?

I can project like following
`| project data["a"],data["b"]` but then I can not process the time. how can i accomplish it ?

Expected output:

One column with time, and other column ( i.e a, b ) for the values

`Time , A , B`

`0:55, 1,2`

Comment: It seems like you assume that a and b necessarily have the same time. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: You might save us some time by supplying a significant data sample

Comment: I am so sorry, I have updated with the data

Comment: Note sure what is desired output. The timestamps are different between a and b. Also not the same number of values.

Comment: The time should be one after another according to the order, on that time if there is any value it should be there if not it should be empty

Comment: I want to project only two column, a and b or a and c together with the time column `Time , a , b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let requested_columns = dynamic(["a","b"]);
datatable(data:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
            "a": {
                "T": [
                    1652167964645,
                    1652168781684,
                    1652168781720,
                    1652169266156,
                    1652169267146,
                    1652169272796,
                    1652169299338
                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    10,
                    6,
                    1252,
                    1555
                ]
            },
            "b": {
                "T": [
                    1652167961657,
                    1652168781720,
                    1652168781818,
                    1652168787377,
                    1652168835734,
                    1652169266108,
                    1652169266125,
                    1652169272798,
                    1652169299328
                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    3,
                    4,
                    6,
                    12,
                    15,
                    16,
                    17,
                    1
                ]
            },
            "c": {
                "T": [
                    1652167960194,
                    1652168787377,
                    1652169266108,
                    1652169272798,
                    1652169299328
                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    3,
                    17,
                    18,
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    )
]
| mv-expand data
| extend key = tostring(bag_keys(data)[0])
| where key in (requested_columns)
| mv-expand T = data[key].T to typeof(long), V = data[key].V to typeof(long)
| evaluate pivot(key, take_any(V), T)
| order by T asc
```

| T | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1652167961657 |  | 1 |
| 1652167964645 | 1 |  |
| 1652168781684 | 2 |  |
| 1652168781720 | 3 | 3 |
| 1652168781818 |  | 4 |
| 1652168787377 |  | 6 |
| 1652168835734 |  | 12 |
| 1652169266108 |  | 15 |
| 1652169266125 |  | 16 |
| 1652169266156 | 10 |  |
| 1652169267146 | 6 |  |
| 1652169272796 | 1252 |  |
| 1652169272798 |  | 17 |
| 1652169299328 |  | 1 |
| 1652169299338 | 1555 |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA82V3WqDMBiGzwu9h%20BRBDf8i9GO3YV4IlJSzTqp1U7TrrLt3vfFFkZ/YraVwRLQ5PVJvvy8%20FVcoJa/bHkneDHPm2q7rjv0iIq%20Zusyx6nBDMtYGJn5MJ0UTEBdVBzL1uzImNNJOp0gKEfh0MGHlyxvX01ZYMrZuTboMejppS6LExDXCWgU%20IFPrDEmpCE8fC1DXXuUidwgcEigY6jj6xjqwro1TBR5XniJZFeGGcnIMSnCuArdUy1LdTbKfbhEFcMhhFzZ2an0cTYYLPd7j0CD3nz/koGqY6hHNbFCj1Bv3I%20D1%20zxWAPjjnv/4DXdPOA19w%209pvKU6gjUllIaSrlB1QflFf3cmPkNxrSdSPtj0hrqe2b5x0ZQ34Zywfpr%20uoem5CWgHlH690d329YXSCZtKTC94JDd8V7SHSi6URb1ku8YMs5SN2Q28zUzkzJvj7zlg9oWSN8kSnN0wixzJwwPIUB2X0MkyPRb3jzhKumXpoWSk6A5BwYVrdj1ZYJjjblrhEYQAsJtuJzVvc4gTniAWvagrdo0UNM1uWfX0LdXccHAAA=)

Comment: How about this?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so so much. I really appricate your time,

Comment: The edit is even better

Comment: See updated answer. It is more dynamic and will ease on your work. Just choose the relevant columns

Comment: My pleasure. one last thing - you can even parametrize the list of columns: `let requested_columns = dynamic(["b","c"]); ... | where key in (requested_columns)`

Comment: small question: what if the there is another entry inside the document and if I want to carry that untill the end. for example, if there is `{ 'metadata': ' metadata', 'data' : {... as in example }}`

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. If you're struggling, open a new post with a relevant data sample and I'll answer it

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301435/project-certain-column-and-carry-on-one-entry-in-every-row