# Project certain column and carry on one entry in every row

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a dataset which looks like the following

```
{
    "metadata":"d_meta_v_1.5.9",
    "data": {
            "a": {
                "T": [
                    1652167964645,
                    1652168781684,
                    1652168781720

                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
                ]
            },
            "b": {
                "T": [
                    1652167961657,
                    1652168781720,
                    1652168781818
                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    3,
                    4
                
                ]
            },
            "c": {
                "T": [
                    1652167960194,
                    1652168787377

                ],
                "V": [
                    1,
                    3
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

I want to select the certain column and carry on the metadata also at the end. a part of this question is working in my perviou question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289683/projectig-certain-sub-documents-in-kusto/72290928?noredirect=1#comment127731842_72290928)
How can I get my desired output ?

```
Metadata, Time, a, b
d_meta_v_1.5.9, <Time>, <value of _a>, < value of b>
d_meta_v_1.5.9, <Time>, <value of _a>, < value of b>
d_meta_v_1.5.9, <Time>, <value of _a>, < value of b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let requested_columns = dynamic(["a","b"]);
datatable(doc:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
            "metadata":"d_meta_v_1.5.9",
            "data": {
                    "a": {
                        "T": [
                            1652167964645,
                            1652168781684,
                            1652168781720
                        ],
                        "V": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3
                        ]
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "T": [
                            1652167961657,
                            1652168781720,
                            1652168781818
                        ],
                        "V": [
                            1,
                            3,
                            4
                        ]
                    },
                    "c": {
                        "T": [
                            1652167960194,
                            1652168787377
                        ],
                        "V": [
                            1,
                            3
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    )
]
| project metadata = doc.metadata, data = doc.data
| mv-expand data = data
| extend key = tostring(bag_keys(data)[0])
| where key in (requested_columns)
| mv-expand T = data[key].T to typeof(long), V = data[key].V to typeof(long)
| evaluate pivot(key, take_any(V), metadata, T)
| order by T asc
```

| metadata | T | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d_meta_v_1.5.9 | 1652167961657 |  | 1 |
| d_meta_v_1.5.9 | 1652167964645 | 1 |  |
| d_meta_v_1.5.9 | 1652168781684 | 2 |  |
| d_meta_v_1.5.9 | 1652168781720 | 3 | 3 |
| d_meta_v_1.5.9 | 1652168781818 |  | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8VUbW%20CMBD%20buJ/aPqpJIyIoqjL/gXhCyGkws05gTKoTLLtv%20%20KON%20mYmLikcD1eZ67Hr3mYpAkh48VFBKiIBTxKkkL8kKiKuXJImQe5VSnM%20prz91OxCU%20sxhYJMJpI9G6Ha/bIWgNsFmwzUfZ185VRhOQXKWiUxoFahGUgWkMjQnVj5Qb1XGCP/oCV/MO8t55Xpk5GvbNkT0ZWSNrqLfRju0xvqzWWrvfOy/1L6Shbovyr5TRv8IPLpT2P/VzJiPekfs1Ax37lgNurcXncc0YXOGt%20zUjvGMzeuak9W23B7b9wAO%20/QBP4T2ocXHCYfg3yXLxDqEk2/mlxqQIje1SJ3ugclVMUj7BOuNp9Ec2BKwlILqECkEpCpkv0jmb8XmAUMGUTPN6vqa0n2%20QQy1dpISdjGvtcCOn2cXDAN9wMDmRVQbilcUinWs6cQ8E7rGgrq7k8YpLINmiFJKhUCeSLyHgacVczLH7aacOEHkEOZlVuDsvwl9rKM0lVgYAAA==)